# load the photo data into the picture using the function loadButtons work through all pixels identifying buttons and placing boxes into the picture

Tags: c++, arrays, image, recursion

The basic outline of the main program is as follows:

- load the photo data into the picture using the function loadButtons
- work through all pixels identifying buttons and placing boxes into the picture
- write the picture data to a new .ppm file
- (outside your program) convert your new `.ppm` file to `.bmp` and view it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class pixel_class {
private:
  int red, green, blue;
  bool exclude;  // if true, do not check this pixel
public:
  void loaddata(int v1, int v2, int v3);
  void datatofile(fstream & ppmfile);
  int getR() { return red; }
  int getG() { return green; }
  int getB() { return blue; }
  void setexclude(bool ex) { exclude = ex; }
  bool getexclude() { return exclude; }
};

void loadButtons();

int total, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;  // MUST be global if used
int screenx, screeny, maxcolours;   // you must use these
pixel_class picture[600][600];      // you must use this

int main() {

  // Step 1 : read in the image from Buttons.ppm
  loadButtons();

  // Step 2 : identify buttons and draw boxes
  ... need to do something here ...

  // Step 3 : output the final .ppm file
  ... need to do something here ...
}

void loadButtons() {
  // load the picture from Buttons.ppm
  int x, y, R, G, B;
  fstream infile;
  string infilename, line;
  infilename = "Buttons.ppm";
  infile.open(infilename.c_str(), fstream::in);
  if (infile.is_open() == false) {
    cout << "ERROR: not able to open " << infilename << endl;
    exit(2);
  }
  getline(infile, line);  // this line is "P3"
  getline(infile, line);  // this line is "# filename"
  infile >> screenx >> screeny;  // this line is the size
  infile >> maxcolours;  // this line is 256
  for (y = 0; y < screeny; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < screenx; x++) {
      infile >> R >> G >> B;
      picture[x][y].loaddata(R, G, B);
      picture[x][y].setexclude(false);
    }
  }
  infile.close();
}

//--------------- methods for the pixel_class ------------
void pixel_class::loaddata(int v1, int v2, int v3) {
  red = v1;
  green = v2;
  blue = v3;
}

void pixel_class::datatofile(fstream & ppmfile) {
  // write the data for one pixel to the ppm file
  ppmfile << red << " " << green;
  ppmfile << " " << blue << "  ";
}
```

Find pixel A at location (x, y) and look for all connected pixels by:
Find pixel B at location (x – 1, y) and look for all connected pixels;
Find pixel C at location (x + 1, y) and look for all connected pixels;
Find pixel D at location (x, y – 1) and look for all connected pixels;
Find pixel E at location (x, y + 1) and look for all connected pixel

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need help completing the missing areas of the code

Comment: That's not how this site is supposed to work. (Please, take the [Tour] and read [ask] if in doubt.) You have to expose your attempt, and specifically to describe what it does in opposition to what it should do (aka. current output vs. expected output). Then somebody may point out what you did wrong.